# React / Karma / WebPack not running test

Tags: reactjs, webpack, jasmine, karma-jasmine

My folder structure is (and I have all the correct npm packages installed)

```
app
  |
  folder1
     reactComponent.js
     |
     testFolder
         reactComponent.spec.js
```

I start my Krama *karma.conf.js* file as, npm test

```
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = function (config) {
  config.set({

    singleRun: true,

    frameworks: ['jasmine'],
    browsers: ['PhantomJS'],

    files: [
      'tests.webpack.js'
    ],

    preprocessors: {
      'tests.webpack.js': [ 'webpack', 'sourcemap' ]
    },

    reporters: [ 'dots' ],

    webpack: {
      devtool: 'inline-source-map',
      module: {
        loaders: [
          { test: /\.js$/, loader: 'babel-loader' }
        ]
      }
    },

    webpackServer: {
      noInfo: true
    }

  });
};
```

*tests.webpack.js*

```
var context = require.context('../app', true, /\*.spec.js$/);
context.keys().forEach(context);
```

Both *karma.conf.js* and *tests.webpack.js* are running.
My spec file *reactComponent.spec.js* is just a simple starter test

```
describe('Simple test', function() {
    it('returns 1 + 1 = 2 ', function() {
        expect(2).toEqual(1 + 1);
    });
});
```

But in the command window (Windows 10) I get

```
D:\development\react\poc9-unittests>npm test

> poc@0.0.0 test D:\development\react\poc9-unittests
> karma start ./testing/karma.conf.js

24 04 2017 11:27:30.822:INFO [karma]: Karma v1.6.0 server started at http://0.0.0.0:9876/
24 04 2017 11:27:30.825:INFO [launcher]: Launching browser PhantomJS with unlimited concurrency
24 04 2017 11:27:30.836:INFO [launcher]: Starting browser PhantomJS
24 04 2017 11:27:33.859:INFO [PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Windows 8 0.0.0)]: Connected on socket YzqWwfSyJoA5P4DbAAAA with id 73371783
PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Windows 8 0.0.0): Executed 0 of 0 ERROR (0.001 secs / 0 secs)
npm ERR! Test failed.  See above for more details.
```

*See above for more details* there's nothing to see and there's no log file generated.

In *tests.webpack.js* if i alter the folder to point to a not existent folder

```
var context = require.context('../appNonExistentFolder ', true, /\*.spec.js$/);
```

I get

```
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve 'file' or 'directory' ../appNonExistentFolder in D:\devel......
```

So it appears I'm running the test runners.
Is my folder RegExp correct ?

What I'm trying to do is run any .spec.js file in any folder under the root folder of app.

If in my *karma.conf.js* file I set

```
   webpackServer: {
      noInfo: false
    }
```

I get a bit more info

```
Hash: f4683f5fa2953dc3a97c
Version: webpack 1.15.0
Time: 61ms
webpack: Compiled successfully.
webpack: Compiling...
Hash: 18eef6f855c83434d040
Version: webpack 1.15.0
Time: 1086ms
           Asset     Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
tests.webpack.js  4.88 kB       0  [emitted]  tests.webpack.js
chunk    {0} tests.webpack.js (tests.webpack.js) 269 bytes [rendered]
    [0] ./testing/tests.webpack.js 109 bytes {0} [built]
    [1] ./app \*.spec.js$ 160 bytes {0} [built]
webpack: Compiled successfully.
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a result of Karma not being able to find your tests;

There can be different reasons behind this, first check the path in the `karma.conf.js`
There could be some missing or misplaced specs in the test file so karma will have nothing to execute. if there is no tests that leads to number of success tests to be 0 and this is read as an error. you can try adding a dummy spec to if it works.

Answer (score 1):

Ahhh, a stupid typo in my RegExp

*tests.webpack.js*  REMOVE the * so that it reads

```
var context = require.context('../app', true, /\.spec.js$/);
context.keys().forEach(context);
```